# Cannot build asmack

Tags: android, compilation, xmpp, asmack

Following the instructions here:
https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/wiki/Build-Instructions-for-Linux

This is what I get:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
Smack git repository git://github.com/Flowdalic/smack.git with branch master
SMACK_LOCAL:false   UPDATE_REMOTE:true  BUILD_CUSTOM:   BUILD_JINGLE:false
PARALLEL_BUILD:false    BASE:/home/pankaj/asmack
## Step 00: initialize
## Step 15: fetching sources
Fetching master branch/commit from git://github.com/Flowdalic/smack.git to smack via git
Already on 'master'
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 20 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
Fetching from http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/qpid/trunk/qpid/java/management/common/src/main/ to qpid at revision HEAD
At revision 1606364.
Fetching from http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/harmony/enhanced/java/trunk/classlib/modules/auth/src/main/java/common/ to harmony at revision HEAD
At revision 1606364.
## Step 20: creating build/src
## Step 25: patch build/src
./00-relocate-javax.security.sh
./10-remove-unused-harmony.sh
./11-remove-nls-harmony.sh
./12-harmony-nls-msg.patch
patching file ./org/apache/harmony/javax/security/auth/login/LoginContext.java
patching file ./org/apache/harmony/javax/security/auth/Subject.java
./13-mock-configuration.patch
patching file ./org/apache/harmony/javax/security/auth/login/Configuration.java
./21-remove-unused-smack.sh
./24-disable-sasl-methods.patch
patching file org/jivesoftware/smack/SASLAuthentication.java
./30-enable-custom-sasl.sh
## Step 30: compile
/home/pankaj/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130917/sdk/platforms/ contains no Android SDKs
You must install at least one Android SDK Platform
You might also check your android-sdk path in local.properties
 or in ANDROID_HOME environment variable
```

But the SDK is alright:

```
pankaj@pankaj-laptop:~/asmack$ ls /home/pankaj/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130917/sdk/platforms/    
android-10  android-17  android-18  android-19
```

I also tried setting path to /home/pankaj/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130917/sdk/ to no avail.
I am able to use the sdk and build other apps just fine. What is wrong?

Comment: Quoting from the output of the script: "You might also check your android-sdk path in local.properties or in ANDROID_HOME environment variable". Is `ANDROID_HOME` set correctly?

Comment: I did set local.properties. ANDROID_HOME should be set to the same path?

Comment: Setting ANDROID_HOME makes no difference. I get exactly the same error.