# asmack xmpp not connected to Ejabbered Server

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I have written XMPP client in java using smack 4.0.6 library. The following lines can successfully connect to the XMPP server in java. But using  asmack-8-4.0.6 library,these lines in android is unable to connect to same XMPP server.

```
ConnectionConfiguration conf = new ConnectionConfiguration(SERVERADDRESS,
            5222);
    conf.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(conf);
connection.connect();
```

I have added following permission in the Android Manifest. Still it unable to connect the server.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The error message is given below

```
` `org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException`
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25243883/cant-establish-a-new-connection-with-asmack-4-0-2

Comment: Note that the first parameter of this ConnectionConfiguration constructor is not the serveraddress. Also have a look at the javadoc of ConnectionException.